# append data to a json when user click on each row

Tags: javascript, json

I have data from a sql server being displayed in a html table. Each row has a `<tr data-json='$Serial_No' >` When the user picks a row it puts the

```
var UserPick = $(this).data('json');
```

Then uses the  Serial_No to filter out from all the data and just picks out the row. How can I get it to append the data for each time the user picks a row.

here is my function

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

     $(function()
     {
          $('tr').on('click',function()
          {
           //when the user picks a row it is stored here.
            var UserPick = $(this).data('json');

    //this is getting all the data the user looked for it can be over 50 rows of info.
            var mike = $('#backup').text(); 

    //this parse the json data
            var objMike = JSON.parse(mike);

            //console.log(mike);

                     //this then filters all the of the parse json data and search for the users picked Serial_No.  

    // How do I append the user picked Serial_No so that each time the users picks a row it doesn't wipe out the NewMike ?

            var NewMike =  objMike.filter(function(ss) 
                {
                    return ss.Serial_No == UserPick;

                });

            //console.log(NewMike); 
    //this puts that new filtered data in to a UpdateJson 
      var UpdateJson = JSON.stringify(NewMike)

      $("#reload").show();

    //then puts it in to a div text for displaying.
    $('#mike').text(UpdateJson);

    //$('#printButton').click

          });

    });

    </script>

<div id='backup'name='backup'  ><?php echo json_encode($json); ?> </div>

<div id='mike' name='mike' ><?php echo json_encode($json); ?></div>
```

so if the input was this

```
[{"Serial_No":"001","Barcode":"M139010-001","part":"F06984-0064","DESCR":"BACC69CCC0064J\/BOEIN, REV R","MFG":"M139010-001","Cable_Length":"64.375 Inches","Test_A":".01","Test_B":".07"},{"Serial_No":"002","Barcode":"M139010-002","part":"F06984-0064","DESCR":"BACC69CCC0064J\/BOEIN, REV R","MFG":"M139010-002","Cable_Length":"64.625 Inches","Test_A":".02","Test_B":".06"},{"Serial_No":"003","Barcode":"M139010-003","part":"F06984-0064","DESCR":"BACC69CCC0064J\/BOEIN, REV R","MFG":"M139010-003","Cable_Length":"64.625 Inches","Test_A":".04","Test_B":".11"},{"Serial_No":"004","Barcode":"M139010-004","part":"F06984-0064","DESCR":"BACC69CCC0064J\/BOEIN, REV R","MFG":"M139010-004","Cable_Length":"64.625 Inches","Test_A":".08","Test_B":".03"},{"Serial_No":"005","Barcode":"M139010-005","part":"F06984-0064","DESCR":"BACC69CCC0064J\/BOEIN, REV R","MFG":"M139010-005","Cable_Length":"64.625 Inches","Test_A":".13","Test_B":".02"},{"Serial_No":"006","Barcode":"M139010-006","part":"F06984-0064","DESCR":"BACC69CCC0064J\/BOEIN, REV R","MFG":"M139010-006","Cable_Length":"64.625 Inches","Test_A":".03","Test_B":".10"},{"Serial_No":"007","Barcode":"M139010-007","part":"F06984-0064","DESCR":"BACC69CCC0064J\/BOEIN, REV R","MFG":"M139010-007","Cable_Length":"64.625 Inches","Test_A":".03","Test_B":".07"},{"Serial_No":"008","Barcode":"M139010-008","part":"F06984-0064","DESCR":"BACC69CCC0064J\/BOEIN, REV R","MFG":"M139010-008","Cable_Length":"64.625 Inches","Test_A":".02","Test_B":".09"},{"Serial_No":"009","Barcode":"M139010-009","part":"F06984-0064","DESCR":"BACC69CCC0064J\/BOEIN, REV R","MFG":"M139010-009","Cable_Length":"64.75 Inches","Test_A":".01","Test_B":".11"},{"Serial_No":"010","Barcode":"M139010-010","part":"F06984-0064","DESCR":"BACC69CCC0064J\/BOEIN, REV R","MFG":"M139010-010","Cable_Length":"64.625 Inches","Test_A":".02","Test_B":".09"},{"Serial_No":"011","Barcode":"M139010-011","part":"F06984-0064","DESCR":"BACC69CCC0064J\/BOEIN, REV R","MFG":"M139010-011","Cable_Length":"64.625 Inches","Test_A":".02","Test_B":".10"},{"Serial_No":"012","Barcode":"M139010-012","part":"F06984-0064","DESCR":"BACC69CCC0064J\/BOEIN, REV R","MFG":"M139010-012","Cable_Length":"64.625 Inches","Test_A":".05","Test_B":".04"},{"Serial_No":"013","Barcode":"M139010-013","part":"F06984-0064","DESCR":"BACC69CCC0064J\/BOEIN, REV R","MFG":"M139010-013","Cable_Length":"64.625 Inches","Test_A":".06","Test_B":".02"}]
```

the user picks Serial_No 1,5,9 the output needs to be

```
[{"Serial_No":"001","Barcode":"M139010-001","part":"F06984-0064","DESCR":"BACC69CCC0064J\/BOEIN, REV R","MFG":"M139010-001","Cable_Length":"64.375 Inches","Test_A":".01","Test_B":".07"},{"Serial_No":"005","Barcode":"M139010-005","part":"F06984-0064","DESCR":"BACC69CCC0064J\/BOEIN, REV R","MFG":"M139010-005","Cable_Length":"64.625 Inches","Test_A":".13","Test_B":".02"},{"Serial_No":"009","Barcode":"M139010-009","part":"F06984-0064","DESCR":"BACC69CCC0064J\/BOEIN, REV R","MFG":"M139010-009","Cable_Length":"64.75 Inches","Test_A":".01","Test_B":".11"}]
```

the current code doesn't append. so if I pick row 1 then click row 2 it only display the last row the user picked row 2.

here is the html there is has php mixed in with it

```
Echo "<tr data-json='$Serial_No' ><td >".$row3["Work Order No"]."-". $row3["Serial No"]."</td>";
                    Echo "<td>".$part."</td>";
                    Echo "<td>".$DESCR."</td>";
                    Echo "<td>" .$row3["Work Order No"]."-". $row3["Serial No"]."</td>";
                    Echo "<td>". $row3["ValueInches"]."</td>";

                    IF(number_format($row3["Value1"],2)[0] < "1"){

                    Echo "<td>".substr($row3["SS1"], -1)." " .substr(number_format($row3["Value1"],2), 1)."</td>";

                }Else{
                    Echo "<td>".substr($row3["SS1"], -1)." " .number_format($row3["Value1"],2)."</td>";

                }

                IF(number_format($row3["Value2"],2)[0] < "1"){
                    Echo "<td>".substr($row3["SS2"], -1)." " .substr(number_format($row3["Value2"],2), 1)."</td> ";

                }Else{
                    Echo "<td>".substr($row3["SS2"], -1)." " .number_format($row3["Value2"],2)."</td></tr>";


                }
```

this is how the pages displays

[What the user see when the page loads the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivuTv.png)

Comment: Hi can we get the code snippet for html table

Comment: ok I have updated the post with the html part of the table and a screen shot of what the user sees

Answer (score 0):

ok so I have this so far

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var store = [] ;

 $(function()
 {
      $('tr').on('click',function()
      {
        var UserPick = $(this).data('json');

        var mike = $('#backup').text(); 

        var objMike = JSON.parse(mike);

        //console.log(objMike);


        var NewMike =  objMike.filter(function(ss) 
            {

                return ss.Serial_No == UserPick;

            });



                store.push(NewMike);



        console.log(store);

  var UpdateJson = JSON.stringify(store)

  alert(UpdateJson);

  $("#reload").show();

$('#mike').text(UpdateJson);

//$('#printButton').click

      });

});

</script>
```

The output of Store is

```
[[{"Serial_No":"013","Barcode":"M139010-013","part":"F06984-0064","DESCR":"BACC69CCC0064J/BOEIN, REV R","MFG":"M139010-013","Cable_Length":"64.625 Inches","Test_A":".06","Test_B":".02"}],[{"Serial_No":"012","Barcode":"M139010-012","part":"F06984-0064","DESCR":"BACC69CCC0064J/BOEIN, REV R","MFG":"M139010-012","Cable_Length":"64.625 Inches","Test_A":".05","Test_B":".04"}]]
```

But it's not formatted the right way. It needs to be

```
[{"Serial_No":"013","Barcode":"M139010-013","part":"F06984-0064","DESCR":"BACC69CCC0064J/BOEIN, REV R","MFG":"M139010-013","Cable_Length":"64.625 Inches","Test_A":".06","Test_B":".02"},{"Serial_No":"012","Barcode":"M139010-012","part":"F06984-0064","DESCR":"BACC69CCC0064J/BOEIN, REV R","MFG":"M139010-012","Cable_Length":"64.625 Inches","Test_A":".05","Test_B":".04"}]
```

I also don't have any logic in place so if the user keeps click a row it just keeps adding it over and over again. It need to remove the row from var store if it already excess in or just add it ones if not.

Answer (score 0):

here is the working answer

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var store = [] ;
var bck = {};

 $(function()
 {
      $('tr').on('click',function()
      {
        var UserPick = $(this).data('json');

        var mike = $('#backup').text(); 

        var objMike = JSON.parse(mike);

        //console.log(objMike);


        var NewMike =  objMike.filter(function(ss) 
            {

                return ss.Serial_No == UserPick;

            });


    //this lets you pick more then 1 row for printing.      
var tyson = NewMike.pop();
if( bck[tyson.Serial_No] == undefined) {
    bck[tyson.Serial_No] = true;
    store.push(tyson);
} else {
    bck[tyson.Serial_No] = null;
    for(var i=0;i<store.length;i++) // parse whole array until you find the guy you want to remove
            if(store[i].Serial_No == tyson.Serial_No) // this is what you was looking for ;-)
                   store.splice(i, 1); // https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/splice 
}



        //console.log(store);

  var UpdateJson = JSON.stringify(store)

  //alert(UpdateJson);

  $("#reload").show();

$('#mike').text(UpdateJson);

//$('#printButton').click

      });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Look the following example. First you need to store the action json array in a place that you can recover it latter (I used `var jsons = [];` as global). Then find if the actual ID is already inside the array. If it is, remove it, otherwise add it and store the array again.

```js
var jsons = [];

$(".row").on('click', function() {
  var data = JSON.parse(this.dataset.json);
  
  // if find the id, remove it
  if (jsons.filter(r => r.id == data.id).length > 0) {
    jsons = jsons.filter(r => r.id != data.id);
  } else {
    jsons.push(data);
  }
  $("#result").html(JSON.stringify(jsons));
});
```

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="row" data-json='{"id":1}'>
    <td>Id 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row" data-json='{"id":2}'>
    <td>Id 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row" data-json='{"id":3}'>
    <td>Id 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row" data-json='{"id":4}'>
    <td>Id 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: What about ones the user pick the row it adds that object to a new json array so ver jsons=[];




NewMike =json.add(jsons)

Comment: if you do that, the value of NewMike will be the length of the json. And json.add doesn't exists.

Comment: what about doing something like using .concat so eveytime the user clicks a row it appends to a string. Then use Json.stringify and put it have in the div text

Comment: you can do that

Comment: Great I have no idea how that can be written.

Answer (score -1):

ok I tried this

```
var jsons = [];

 $(function()
 {
      $(".row").on("click", function()
      {
      var data = JSON.parse(this.dataset.json);





  if (jsons.filter(r => r.Serial_No == data.Serial_No).length > 0) {
    jsons = jsons.filter(r => r.Serial_No != data.Serial_No);
  } else {
    jsons.push(data);
  }

  $("#mike").html(JSON.stringify(jsons));



    console.log(jsons); 




      });

});
```

I get a Syntax error on

```
if (jsons.filter(r => r.Serial_No == data.Serial_No).length > 0) {
```

Comment: Try this. 
`jsons.filter(function(r) { return r.Serial_No == data.Serial_No}).length`

Comment: Nope it's not liking that